# Extending default Jackson deserialization

Tags: jackson, deserialization

How can one obtain a default deserialized object in a custom Jackson deserializer?

I have an object which contains some fields which are not to be serialized, but which I wish to always be populated upon deserialization. In other words, a post-deserialize step.

I have created my own deserializer and annotated the class with a corresponding `@JsonDeserialize`, but I don't want to deserialize each field in the domain object by hand. Is there a way to get the regular deserialized object so I can just populate my custom fields? (Or else, just register a post-deserialization processor on a bean)

I have seen the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522618/is-there-any-jackson-json-strategy-using-annotations-or-another-way-that-will) which hints at an answer, but I'm sufficiently unaware of the Jackson API to determine how best to actually effect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using a `BeanSerializerModifier` and extending `BeanSerializerBase`, as per @ryanp's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15365957/2032064).